# Canvas: How to modify ImageData pixels that exist within a custom path?

Tags: javascript, canvas, getimagedata, putimagedata

I'm trying to create an experience where a user can move a custom cursor over an image and alter the pixels that live within that custom cursor.

In the `mousemove` event, I try to recreate this custom cursor path and use [isPointInPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) to determine if the custom cursor is "over" a given point in the main canvas's context.

The code does alter some pixels in the main canvas. However, the following unexpected behaviors are listed below:

- moving the cursor alters the pixels of more than one area in the main canvas
- the x and y coordinates of the main canvas (derived from imageData) are not correct

(See the image below)

[image: example altered pixels showing the unexpected behavior of the code]

Why is this happening? How could the code be changed such that the custom cursor (aka circle) only changes pixels corresponding to that part of the main canvas?

```js
let image;
let imageData;

const cursorCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const cursorCanvasContext = cursorCanvas.getContext("2d");
cursorCanvas.width = 100;
cursorCanvas.height = 100;
drawCursor();

const imageCanvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
imageCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
imageCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const imageCanvasContext = imageCanvas.getContext("2d");

document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  image = event.target;
  image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  drawBackground();
  imageData = imageCanvasContext.getImageData(
    0,
    0,
    imageCanvas.width,
    imageCanvas.height
  );
});

window.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    if (imageData) {
      imageCanvasContext.beginPath();
      imageCanvasContext.arc(
        event.clientX,
        event.clientY,
        cursorCanvas.width / 2,
        0,
        2 * Math.PI
      );
      imageCanvasContext.closePath();

      for (let i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
        const y = Math.floor(i / imageData.width);
        const x = i - y * imageData.width;

        if (imageCanvasContext.isPointInPath(x, y)) {
          imageData.data[i] = 40;
          imageData.data[i + 1] = 40;
          imageData.data[i + 2] = 40;
        }
      }
      imageCanvasContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }

    imageCanvasContext.drawImage(
      cursorCanvas,
      event.clientX - cursorCanvas.width / 2,
      event.clientY - cursorCanvas.height / 2
    );
  });
});

function drawBackground() {
  imageCanvasContext.clearRect(
    0,
    0,
    imageCanvas.width,
    imageCanvas.height
  );

  if (image) {
    const ratio =
      window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ?
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight :
      window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth;

    imageCanvasContext.drawImage(
      image,
      0,
      0,
      image.width,
      image.height,
      0,
      0,
      ratio * imageCanvas.width,
      ratio * imageCanvas.height
    );
  }
}

function drawCursor() {
  cursorCanvasContext.beginPath();
  cursorCanvasContext.arc(
    cursorCanvas.width / 2,
    cursorCanvas.width / 2,
    cursorCanvas.width / 2,
    0,
    2 * Math.PI
  );
  cursorCanvasContext.stroke();
  cursorCanvasContext.closePath();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

canvas {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/vzGhITt.jpeg" />
<canvas />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it seems that I have miscalculated the x and y coordinates of the imageData.

Incorrect:

```
const y = Math.floor(i / imageData.width);
const x = i - y * imageData.width;
```

Correct:

```
const x = (i / 4) % imageData.width;
const y = Math.floor(i / 4 / imageData.width);
```

```js
let image;
let imageData;

const cursorCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const cursorCanvasContext = cursorCanvas.getContext("2d");
cursorCanvas.width = 100;
cursorCanvas.height = 100;
drawCursor();

const imageCanvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
imageCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
imageCanvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const imageCanvasContext = imageCanvas.getContext("2d");

document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  image = event.target;
  image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  drawBackground();
  imageData = imageCanvasContext.getImageData(
    0,
    0,
    imageCanvas.width,
    imageCanvas.height
  );
});

window.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    if (imageData) {
      imageCanvasContext.beginPath();
      imageCanvasContext.arc(
        event.clientX,
        event.clientY,
        cursorCanvas.width / 2,
        0,
        2 * Math.PI
      );
      imageCanvasContext.closePath();

      for (let i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
        const x = (i / 4) % imageData.width;
        const y = Math.floor(i / 4 / imageData.width);

        if (imageCanvasContext.isPointInPath(x, y)) {
          imageData.data[i] = 40;
          imageData.data[i + 1] = 40;
          imageData.data[i + 2] = 40;
        }
      }
      imageCanvasContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    }

    imageCanvasContext.drawImage(
      cursorCanvas,
      event.clientX - cursorCanvas.width / 2,
      event.clientY - cursorCanvas.height / 2
    );
});

function drawBackground() {
  imageCanvasContext.clearRect(
    0,
    0,
    imageCanvas.width,
    imageCanvas.height
  );

  if (image) {
    const ratio =
      window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ?
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight :
      window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth;

    imageCanvasContext.drawImage(
      image,
      0,
      0,
      image.width,
      image.height,
      0,
      0,
      ratio * imageCanvas.width,
      ratio * imageCanvas.height
    );
  }
}

function drawCursor() {
  cursorCanvasContext.beginPath();
  cursorCanvasContext.arc(
    cursorCanvas.width / 2,
    cursorCanvas.width / 2,
    cursorCanvas.width / 2,
    0,
    2 * Math.PI
  );
  cursorCanvasContext.stroke();
  cursorCanvasContext.closePath();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

canvas {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/vzGhITt.jpeg" />
<canvas />
```